# Unable to load 'sap/m/HarveyBallMicroChart.js' from https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/m/HarveyBallMicroChart.js: in SAP UI5

Tags: xml, sapui5

ui5loader-dbg.js:1336 Uncaught (in promise) Error: failed to load 'sap/m/HarveyBallMicroChart.js' from https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/m/HarveyBallMicroChart.js: script load erro

Comment: @ConorNeilson As show in the answer, the cause of the error is pretty obvious if someone knows SAPUI5. In this case, a minimal example is not absolutely required.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to require the control from the `sap.m` lib whereas it should be from `sap.suite.ui.microchart` instead.

This is caused probably because of missing namespace when defining the XML view. Add and use the `xmlns` accordingly. E.g.:

```xml
<microchart:HarveyBallMicroChart xmlns:microchart="sap.suite.ui.microchart" ... >
```